# How do I get Xcode 4.1 code completion to work automatically?

Tags: c++, xcode, autocomplete

I just bought a MBP and trying out Xcode. I know code completion works fine when pressing 'Escape', but how can it work automatically with Xcode 4.1? For example, pressing down '.' in C++?

I read several posts on this. Some suggest going to preferences and turning it on, but I didn't see any option. Can you please provide a list of steps?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if C++ is supported...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the preferences > Text editing > Editing > Code completion > Suggest completion as I type.

Comment: This only displays the object name while typing it. When I press '.' for a member variable/function, then this preference doesn't work.

Comment: This is how Xcode works. The better you can do is ask an enhancement request at bugreport.apple.com